# Unable to form the required regex in C

Tags: c, regex, posix

I am trying to write a regex which can search a string and return true if it matches with the regex and false otherwise.

Check should ensure string is wildcard domain name of a website.

Example:

- *.cool.dude is valid
- *.cool is not valid
- abc.cool.dude is not valid

So I had written something which like this

```
\\*\\.[.*]\\.[.*]
```

However, this is also allowing a *.. string as valid string because * means 0 or infinite occurrences.

I am looking for something which ensures that at-least 1 occurrence of the string happens.

Example:
*.a.b -> valid but *.. -> invalid

how to change the regex to support this?

I have already tried doing something like this:

```
\\*\\.([.*]{1,})\\.([.*]{1,}) -> doesnt work

\\*\\.([.+])\\.(.+) -> doesnt work

^\\*\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+ -> doesnt work
```

I have tried a bunch of other options as well and have failed to find a solution. Would be great if someone can provide some input.

PS. Looking for a solution which works in C.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It should be same for both right ? I need to add it in a solution which has both C and C++ code bases.

Comment: @deepakchaurasiacoen What library are you using? C++ has `std::regex`. POSIX has `regex.h`. You should be clear about that.

Comment: @user17732522 I am trying using regex.h

Comment: For C++, the pattern `R"(\*\.\w+\.\w+)"` should work. Check https://godbolt.org/z/81aEoz11h. I suggest you change your `[.*]` for something like `[a-zA-Z]+`. If you cannot use raw literals for patterns, i.e. `R"()"`, you'll have to use double backslashes as you are doing.

Comment: @rturrado,
Thanks a ton for your response. I tried doing something like [a-zA-Z]+ but it still gives pattern not found actually.
Example to just verify *.cool is valid
Ref:
```` 
value = regcomp( &regex, "^\\*\\.[a-zA-Z]+$", 0); -> fails

Comment: You still need `[a-zA-Z]+` for your second `[.*]`. Summing up: `^\\*\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$`.

Comment: @rturrado, yes yes. I have tried exactly this string. If you try testing *.abc.com against it, it will fail. :(

Comment: Ah OK. Make sure you don't have whitespaces at the beginning and end of your input strings; that would be a cause of failure. And I would also try using single backslashes (forget what I said two comments above :)).

Comment: @rturrado,
there is no extra whitespace in the string.

'code'
   value = regcomp( &regex, "^\\*\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$", 0);
  
   value = regexec( &regex, "*.abc.com",
                    0, NULL, 0);

This still fails. Can you give an example of how you are saying to use single backlashes.

Comment: 1) Notice you are writing `\*` instead of `\\*`. 2) Try both `^\\*\\.[a-zA-Z]+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$` and `^\*\.[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$`.

Comment: @rturrado,
Yes I have tried with both double slash (\\). For some reason when I am copy pasting it in comments, it sometimes deletes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[.*]` does not mean "0 or more occurrences" of anything. It means "a single character, either a (literal) `.` or a (literal) `[*]`". `[…]` defines a *character class*, which matches exactly one character from the specified set. Brackets are not even remotely the same as parentheses.

So if you wanted to express "zero or more of any character except newline", you could just write `.*`. That's what `.*` means. And if you wanted "one or more" instead of "zero or more", you could change the `*` to a plus, *as long as you remember that `regex.h` regexes should **always** be compiled with the `REG_EXTENDED` flag*. Without that flag, `+` is just an ordinary character. (And there are a lot of other inconveniences.)

But that's probably not really what you want. My guess is that you want something like:

```
^[*]([.][A-Za-z0-9_]+){2,}$
```

although you'll have to correct the character class to specify the precise set of characters you think are legitimate.

Again, don't forget the crucial `REG_EXTENDED` flag when you call `regcomp`.

Some notes:

- The `{2,}` requires at least two components after the `*`, so that `*.cool` doesn't match.
- The `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the regex "anchor" the match to the entire input. That stops the pattern matching just a part of the input, but it might not be exactly what you want, either.
- Finally, I deliberately used a single-character character class to force `[*]` and `[.]` to be ordinary characters. I find that a lot more readable than falling timber (`\\`) and it avoids having to think about the combination of string escaping and regex-escaping.

For more information, I highly recommend reading [man regcomp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html) and [man 7 regex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html). A good introduction to regexes might be useful, as well.